# What difference betwwen Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) and Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript

```
>Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)
[Function: Empty]

>Object.prototype
{}
```

why I got difference result? But if I use:

```
>Object.getPrototypeOf({})
{}
```

everything is fine. Is any point I missed about getPrototypeOf??

Comment: You don't really explain which result you expected, but I tried to explain the difference between `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object)` and `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`Object.prototype`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) is the object from which all other objects inherit. It is at the *root* of the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for built-in objects. From the MDN documentation:

> All objects in JavaScript are descended from `Object`; all objects inherit methods and properties from `Object.prototype`, although they may be overridden [...]

[**`Object.getPrototypeOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) is a convenience method to *get* the prototype of a specific object. From the MDN documentation:

> The `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method returns the prototype (i.e. the internal `[[Prototype]]`) of the specified object.

Different types of objects can have different prototypes.

Examples:

```
> Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Function.prototype
true
```

`Object` is a **function**, hence its prototype is `Function.prototype`.

```
> Object.getPrototypeOf(/foo/) === RegExp.prototype
true
```

`/foo/` creates a **regular expression**, hence its prototype is `RegExp.prototype`.

```
> Object.getPrototypeOf([]) === Array.prototype
true
```

`[]` creates an **array**, its prototype is `Array.prototype`.

```
> Object.getPrototypeOf({}) === Object.prototype
true
```

`{}` creates a simple **object**, its prototype is `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question: why?

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Function.prototype;    // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object) === Object.prototype;      // false
```

though:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Function.prototype); // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Object.prototype);   // false
```

Object and Function behave the same wrt getPrototypeOf, though Object.prototype and Function.prototype are different.
The internal [[prototype]] of Function === its property, but the internal [[prototype]] of Object is not its property.

Looks peculiar (I don't see any other similar situation).

Yes indeed, Object is a function, so is Array, etc., so is Function. All are 'function'. Shouldn't we say that "objects are first-class functions"? (instead of reverse? just joking)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but i just went through this and i didn't find a full picture anywhere. Assuming you're creating a custom constructor function `Foo`, it's like this:

[image: JS proto diagram]

Watch that both `Object.__proto__` and `Function.__proto__` point to Function.prototype, because both `Object` and `Function` *are* functions, just like `Foo`.